# Calculating Object Size in Heap Memory

Tags: java, object, memory-management, package, heap-memory

Can we find how much space is allocated to an object in heap memory in java ? Is there any class or methods which we can use to find the memory allotted to the Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a heap dump and then you can analyse it using Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) with MAT you can see figures such as Shallow Heap and Retained Heap. The metric you are looking for is **Shallow Heap**, which means the amount of memory consumed by an object. Furthermore, the metric called Retained Heap means the amount of memory released if an object is garbage collected.

The following picture shows an example of Shallow Heap

[image: Shallow heap related to a memory leak issue]

For a better explanation about Retained Heap, you can check this https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/welcome.html and/or this https://dzone.com/articles/eclipse-mat-shallow-heap-retained-heap

The following link shows a presentation about analyzing memory leak issues that could be useful for you https://www.slideshare.net/RaulCastillo36/analyzing-a-memory-leak-problem.